# Android Layout for calendar control

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking to build a layout as above using linear/relative layouts with textbox.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add background style to root layout for rounded corner and done

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="25"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sept \n2016"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#999999"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="25"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sept \n2016"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```